# How to delete a Firebase db entry when user has been inactive for some time (not logged out, but hasn't visited the page in a while)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Currently when a user clicks 'logout' their session is terminated and a database entry is removed. All other users see that database entry so the goal is for users to see each other's data but only while they are logged in.

Example: person A and person B are both logged in and they can both "see each other". However when person B logs out, person A can no longer see them. But if person B simply closes the browser without hitting logout button, their data remains.

Can Firebase check if a user has been inactive for 15 minutes for example (or any arbitrary amount of time), and then delete their database entries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to measure a lack of activity. To do that, you need to record activity, such as updating a timestamp in the user record on each pageload. Then to measure a lack of activity, you would query for users with the timestamp older than your threshold.

To act on inactive users, you would need some kind of separate maintenance process running. It's easier to filter your list of active users based on the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks! So Firebase has no built-in functionality for that type of maintenance process?

Comment: Well you could look at systems like Firebase Queue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue